# React: Add Complex object to Element

Tags: reactjs

Heelo Eveyone.

I am integrating Unlimint payment gateway and their library is written in vanilla JS. They have the following example which I tested successfully:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <unlimint-ui-pay-form></unlimint-ui-pay-form>

    <script>
      const props = {
        urls: {
          generateMobileToken: 'https://sandbox.cardpay.com/demo-merchant/mobile/generate_token',
          payment: 'https://sandbox.cardpay.com/api/mobile/payment',
        },
        enableRedirect: false,
        data: {
          merchantName: 'Merchant Name',
          merchantOrder: {
            description: 'description',
            id: '21513-216',
          },
          paymentMethod: 'BANKCARD',
          paymentData: {
            amount: '9700.00',
            currency: 'USD',
          },
          customer: {
            email: 'test@test.test',
          },
          returnUrls: {
            successUrl: 'https://example.com/success',
            declineUrl: 'https://example.com/decline',
          },
        },
        callbacks: {
          resolve: (data) => {
            console.log('resolve callback, data:', data);
          },
          reject: (error) => {
            console.log('reject callback, error:', error);
          },
        },
      };
      const cardForm = document.querySelector('unlimint-ui-pay-form');
      cardForm.props = props;
    </script>
    <script src="unlimint-pay-form.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to do the same in React. I have come up with this(which stills doesn't work because the assignent to properties doesn't do the same:

```
const UnlimintPayment : React.FC<PaymentFormProps> = () => {
    const ref = useRef<Element>();

    const UnlimintForm = () => React.createElement('unlimint-ui-pay-form', {
    ref: ref,
});

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!ref.current) {
            return; 
        }

        const cardForm = document.querySelector('unlimint-ui-pay-form') as any;
        cardForm.props = {
            urls: {
                generateMobileToken: 'https://sandbox.cardpay.com/demo-merchant/mobile/generate_token',
                payment: 'https://sandbox.cardpay.com/api/mobile/payment',
            },
            enableRedirect: false,
            data: {
                merchantName: 'Merchant Name',
                merchantOrder: {
                    description: 'description',
                    id: '21513-216',
                },
                paymentMethod: 'BANKCARD',
                paymentData: {
                    amount: '9700.00',
                    currency: 'USD',
                },
                customer: {
                    email: 'test@test.test',
                },
                returnUrls: {
                    successUrl: 'https://example.com/success',
                    declineUrl: 'https://example.com/decline',
                },
            },
            callbacks: {
                resolve: (data: any) => {
                    console.log('resolve callback, data:', data);
                },
                reject: (error: any) => {
                    console.log('reject callback, error:', error);
                },
            },
        };
        require("@unlimint/client-js-sdk/unlimint-pay-form.js")
    }, [ref])

    return <UnlimintForm />
}
export default UnlimintPayment;
```

The assignement of "props" here doesn't work. Notice the workaround I ended up with casting as any. Still it doesn't seem to work because it actually write the props in html (which the example they provide doesn't). What am I doing wrong?